Remove Namspaces from jaxb unmarshall
I have a below code which is adding some default namespaces which i want to avoid it.
Unmarshaller marshaller = sResponseJaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
     ResponseType response = (ResponseType) ((JAXBElement<?>)marshaller.unmarshal(aData)).getValue();

aData is org.w3c.Dom.Element object.
Is there any setting we can set to remove default namespaces or something we can do in .xjb files?
